# how to access the i element of the void* string?

Tags: c

i have

```
void *string; // it is array of characters different encodings
```

i read it with my func, after that i want to print it, all good, it prints right. and after that i want to print i character (first for example), how can i access him?

```
string=readline();
printf("%s\n", string);
printf("%c\n", ??? );
```

i tried this, but it doesn't work

```
string=readline();
printf("%s\n", string);
printf("%c\n", string + sizeof(void *);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data is representable as `char` then simply cast and de-reference:

```
printf("%c\n", *(char*)string);
```

Or alternatively:

```
char* str = string;
...
printf("%c\n", str[i]);
```

Comment: the first one is what i need, but if there will be cyrillic character (russians use cyrillic) or character from another encoding it doesn't print. but the string prints right with it. how can i fix it?

Comment: @Alexander That would depend on what format the console is using. Generally C uses `wchar_t` and the wchar.h library for extended symbol tables.

Comment: then i should `#include <wchar.h>` and `printf("%c\n", *(wchar_t *)string);`?

Comment: @Alexander Again, it depends on what format the console of your OS is using and what `wchar_t` corresponds to for the particular compiler. Is it UTF-8, is it something else.